# Не правильно работает блокировка кнопки и не срабатывает Read Only ячейки

Tags: winapi, button, combobox

Есть две Combobox ячейки и мне нужно, чтобы  они были Read Only.
Я делаю `ES_READONLY`, но в них все равно можно ввести значения. Не знаю, почему не  срабатывает.

```
hStartVertexCombo = CreateWindow(L"Combobox", NULL,
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWN | ES_READONLY,
97, 70, 120, 110, hWnd, NULL, 
hInst, NULL);

hEndVertexCombo = CreateWindow(L"Combobox", NULL,
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWN | ES_READONLY,
307, 70, 120, 110, hWnd, NULL, 
hInst, NULL);
```

Далее, мне нужно, чтобы кнопка `Find Path` становилась активной, когда я что-то выбираю в ОБОИХ Combobox , а сейчас она у меня  становится активной сразу после того, как я  выбираю в одном.

Как это можно исправить?

```
if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
{
    SendMessage(hStartVertexCombo, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
    SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
    return;
}

else if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE)
{
    EnableWindow(hFindPathButton, 1);
}
```

UPD:

```
if ((startIndex == CB_ERR) || (endIndex == CB_ERR))
{
    SetWindowText(hFilePathEdit, L"Error");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать COMBOBOX только для чтения (заменить поле редактирования статическим окошком) используйте для него при создании стиль CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, а не CBS_DROPDOWN (смотрите [Combo Box Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Флажок ES_READONLY не влияет на элемент COMBOBOX.

Для того, чтобы подсвечивать кнопку как Вам надо, измените Ваш обработчик:
    `...
    else if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE)
    {
        if (SendMessage(hStartVertexCombo,CB_GETCURSEL,0,0)!=CB_ERR &&
            SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo,CB_GETCURSEL,0,0)!=CB_ERR)
                EnableWindow(hFindPathButton, TRUE);
        else EnableWindow(hFindPathButton, FALSE);
    }`

Comment: а что возвращать в такой проверке(UPD?  я   написал чтобы вывело Error,  но может нужно по правилам что то  другое?

Comment: Возврат из оконных обработчиков зависит исключительно от того, каким образом возвращаемое значение будет интерпретировано системой. Т.е. в зависимости от того, в каком сообщении Вы проводите проверку, смотрите в MSDN как интерпретируются возвращаемые значения для данного сообщения. Например, для WM_COMMAND Вы должны вернуть 0, если обработали указанное сообщение, или не нуль в противном случае